Ios build issue with my React-Native expo app
I'm currently working on a React Native Expo app and running into a build error when trying to compile for iOS using EAS Build. The error involves a redefinition of module 'ReactCommon'. Despite following the usual troubleshooting steps—like cleaning the project, reinstalling pods, and ensuring proper pod configurations—the issue persists.
Despite these efforts, the build continues to fail. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has expertise in troubleshooting iOS builds for React Native projects, your advice would be greatly appreciated!
Feel free to DM me(https://www.linkedin.com/in/shubhang-pandey-608531186) or comment below with any suggestions or solutions. Thanks in advance for your help!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
